# I have a property value with '#' symbol in property file Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, properties

Is there any way to resolve Hash # symbol as per my knowledge it is taking the password as comment.

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://11.11.0.141:3307/XXXXX_HDS_SHHD
database.user=Dheeraj1
database.password=#csd#@12342@ghba
```

Comment: Why you think it is talking password as comment? After equal sign (=), # is a valid symbol.

Comment: Did you tried replacing the hash(#) with \\# in your code. Notice the double slashes.

Answer (score 0):

**#** is not considered as a comment in your case

```
database.password=#csd#@12342@ghba
```

but in this case its considered as a comment

```
#database.password=#csd#@12342@ghba
```

Note ⚠️:  Don't reveal an actual secrets in your question